# Largest rank submatrix of a skew symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the following statement true?

Given a skew symmetric matrix M, among all of its largest rank sub-matrix, there must be one that is the principal submatrix of M.

Comment: It's true, for both symmetric and skew-symmetric matrices, over an arbitrary field (and also hermitian...), and known as "Principal minor theorem". For a generalization, see Theorem 2.9 [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/01f3/f8048ed0c7c2e55f3498144b65e49cfabbf2.pdf) (*V. Kodiyalam, T. Lam, R. Swan,
Determinantal ideals, Pfaffian ideals, and the principal minor theorem. Noncommutative rings, group rings, diagram algebras and their applications, 35-60,
Contemp. Math., 456, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 2008*). I haven't found a more classical reference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. Suppose that you have a general $n \times n$ matrix *M*.  The coefficient of $(-x)^k$ in the characteristic polynomial is the sum of all the principal minors of the matrix of size *n-k*. From this it follows that the "rank computed by the principal minors" can differ from the actual rank of the matrix only if the matrix is not diagonalizable. Since skew-symmetric matrices are diagonalizable, the result follows.

Comment: Nice, I think this will works for any matrix $M$
whose $0$-eigenspace is the same as the generalized
$0$-eigenspace, that is the set of all vectors killed by a power
of $M$.

Comment: Indeed, the "rank by principal minors" computes the multiplicity of 0 in the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 3):

Another proof: For any $I$ and $J$ two subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ of the same cardinality, let $D(I,J)$ be the minor in rows $I$ and columns $J$. Let $Pf(I)$ be the Pfaffian $\sqrt{D(I,I)}$. We set $D(\emptyset, \emptyset) = Pf(\emptyset) =1$.

**Lemma:** Every $D(I,J)$ can be written as a quadratic polynomial in the $Pf(K)$'s.

**Proof of Lemma:** I claim that
$$D(I,J) = \sum_{S \subset J \ |J| \ \mbox{even}} (-1)^{|S|/2} \ Pf(I \cup (J \setminus S)) \ Pf(S).$$
(There may be some sign errors.)
Every term on the right can be visualized as corresponding to a perfect matching on the indices $J \sqcup I$. Focus on one particular term. Let $(j_1, j_1')$, $(j_2, j_2')$, ..., $(j_r, j_r')$ be the matchings which lie within $J$. This term will appear only when $S$ is a union of some set of these matchings. The total contribution of this term is thus $\sum_{k=0}^r (-1)^k \binom{r}{k}$. This is $1$ for $r=0$ and $0$ for $r>0$.

**Application of lemma:**  Suppose that $Pf(K)=0$ for all $K$ with $|K| > r$. Let $|I|=|J|>r$. Write $D(I,J)$ as a quadratic polynomial in the $Pf(K)$'s. Then, by degree considerations, for every monomial $Pf(K) Pf(K')$ in that quadratic polynomial, one of $Pf(K)$ and $Pf(K')$ is $0$. So imposing that all the principal minors of size $>r$ be $0$ implies that the same is true for non-principal minors.